# When does a city recover from occupied status?

Tags: civilization-6

I lost my capital to a naval invasion from the AI around the renaissance era. After some fighting I eventually took it back. It now counted as occupied.

After the war ended it was still occupied and it never recovered, it stayed like that having no growth until the end of the game.

There was no options about the city in the peace negotiation or in later diplomacy. Did I miss something about occupation mechanics or could this be a bug?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, did your city suffer from occupation status or was the label just there?

Comment: It did suffer the effects, like no growth for the rest of the game.

Comment: If you never ceded the city, it shouldn't have counted as occupied when you liberated it. Sounds like a bug

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging and from what I can find, [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/289070/discussions/0/154642321537746712/) link generalizes what I found.

It seems as though since the city 'belongs' to a another civ, it is under hostile military control until you completely wipe out the original owner. I play the game a bit and can look to test it tonight, but I believe I had this problem before and it also when away when I wiped out the original owner.

Will update when I test it myself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might have been fixed since.

I conquered an event city 4 or 5 turns ago and as soon as they made peace with me out stopped showing up as occupied.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The label "occupied: no growth" goes away after fully conquering the player who originally owned the city/ies taken.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).